# How to use diffrent DbContext per user in mvc core 2.2

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, entity-framework-core

i have some company and many user for that.
now i need to have one database per company.

have to solve this problem in MVC Core. and control DI

Comment: You are designing an application for multiple tenancy.  Google for Multi-tenant asp.net core, ef core.  This should help show you as you have a few ways to solve this.  Something like https://gunnarpeipman.com/series/multi-tenant-aspnet-core/ shuold help.

Comment: Your question is too broad to answer.  I have voted to close it but added a comment to help you on your journey. :-)  Good luck and as you research and try things please feel free to come back and ask more narrow questions that we can help you with.

Comment: Are the DbContext same except connecting to different databases? Or, the DbContext are total different, if so, you may consider implement DbContextFactory which is used to create dbContext with user identifier.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create several DataBaseContext classes like this

```
 using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

    namespace Data.Models
    {
        public class FirstDataContext: DbContext
        {
            public DbSet<User> Users{ get; set; }
            public FirstDataContext(DbContextOptions<FirstDataContext> options)
                : base(options)
            {

            }
        }


        public class SecondDataContext : DbContext
        {
            public DbSet<User> Users{ get; set; }
            public SecondDataContext(DbContextOptions<SecondDataContext> options)
                : base(options)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

then on  appsettings.json add several connection strings that contains address of database

```
    {
      "ConnectionStrings": {
        "FirstCompany": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=company1;Trusted_Connection=True;"
      },
         "SecondCompany": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=company2;Trusted_Connection=True;"
      },
    }
```

then go to StartUp.cs

```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {

                string FirstCompany= Configuration.GetConnectionString("FirstCompany");
string SecondCompany= Configuration.GetConnectionString("SecondCompany");

                services.AddDbContext<FirstDataContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(connection));

services.AddDbContext<SecondDataContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(connection));
                services.AddMvc();
            }
```

DI:

```
     public class HomeController: Controller
     {    
          FirstDataContext fdcntxt;
          SecondDataContext sdcntxt;

          public HomeController (FirstDataContext fdcntxt, SecondDataContext sdcntxt)
          {
               this.fdcntxt = fdcntxt;
               this.sdcntxt = sdcntxt;
          }
      }
```

I think this should be works).